# ¿ Como crear un encabezado personalizado con TCPDF?

Tags: php, pdf

Estoy generando un pdf con la librería tcpdf pero deseo crear un encabezado con una altura, titulo y imagen diferente a la que viene en esta, en realidad no se mucho sobre esta libreria y no comprendo algunas cosas, tengo lo siguiente:

```
// Include the main TCPDF library (search for installation path).
require_once('PDF/tcpdf.php');
// 
class PDF{
    private $pdf;
    function __construct($titulo){

        $this->pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

        // set document information NOTA: datos solo informativos no muestra 
        $this->pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
        $this->pdf->SetAuthor('Personal');
        // $this->pdf->SetTitle($Titulo);
        // $this->pdf->SetSubject($Asunto);

        //$this->pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');

        // Header los parametros PDF_HEADER_LOGO y PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH se encuentran declarados en config/tcpdf_config.php 
        // $ln (string) header image logo
        // $lw (string) header image logo width in mm
        // $ht (string) string to print as title on document header
        // $hs (string) string to print on document header
        // $tc (array) RGB array color for text.
        // $lc (array) RGB array color for line.

        // set default header data
        $this->pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE, $hs=$titulo);

        // set header and footer fonts
        $this->pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
        $this->pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

        // set default monospaced font
        $this->pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

        // set margins
        $this->pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
        $this->pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
        $this->pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

        // set auto page breaks
        $this->pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

        // set image scale factor
        $this->pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

        // set some language-dependent strings (optional)
        if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/spa.php')) {
            require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/spa.php');
            $this->pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
        }

    }

    function estructuraPag($contenidoHTML){
        // Seleccionamos la tipografia y tamano de letra
        $this->pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 10);

        // Comienza la pag
        $this->pdf->AddPage();

        // Contenido pdf
        $contenidoHTML;

        $this->pdf->writeHTML($contenidoHTML, true, false, true, false, '');
        // reset pointer to the last page
        $this->pdf->lastPage();

    }


    function generarPdf($file, $name){

        //$file = '../archivos/actas/'.$idContrato;
        if(!is_dir($file))
        {
            if(!mkdir($file, 0777)){
                echo "error";
                exit();
            }
        }

        // Close and output PDF document
        // I: send the file inline to the browser (default). The plug-in is used if available. The name given by name is used when one selects the "Save as" option on the link generating the PDF.
        // D: send to the browser and force a file download with the name given by name.
        // F: save to a local server file with the name given by name.
        // S: return the document as a string (name is ignored).
        // FI: equivalent to F + I option
        // FD: equivalent to F + D option
        // E: return the document as base64 mime multi-part email attachment (RFC 2045)

        $this->pdf->Output($file.'/'.$name.'.pdf', 'FI');
        exit();
    }

}
```

aqui algunos [ejemplos](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php),

Answer (score 1):

Yo el encabezado que uso en mis páginas es con el código siguiente

```
$PDF_HEADER_TITLE="Titulo del PDF";
$PDF_HEADER_STRING="SEgunda linea";
$PDF_HEADER_LOGO="imagen"; //Solo me funciona si esta dentro de la carpeta images de la libreria

$this->pdf->SetHeaderData($PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, $PDF_HEADER_TITLE, $PDF_HEADER_STRING);

// set header and footer fonts
$this->pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$this->pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));
```

Answer (score 0):

Desconozco tu nivel y experiencia en PHP pero por lo que veo lo que tienes que hacer con ese archivo es sustituir las constantes (todas las variables que ves escritas en mayúsculas) por valores tuyos, bien sean literales o bien sea definiendo dichas constantes.

He buscado rápidamente algo de info acerca de TCPDF en español por si te sirve de ayuda, aquí tienes entre otras cosas un listado de las constantes y su utilidad:
https://es.scribd.com/doc/218944062/Manual-de-Tc-PDF

Es obligatorio también incluir aquí un link a la doc oficial:
https://tcpdf.org/docs/source_docs/classTCPDF/

Si tienes dudas concretas escríbelas aquí y las iremos resolviendo.

Salu2

Comment: Como estas @manuelbcd, no creo que sea tanto como sustituir variables, he mirado un ejemplo de como hacerlo pero no comprendo muy bien algunas cosas [mira](https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_003/) por eso formule la pregunta, el enlace me puede ayudar a despejar algunas dudas muchas gracias por tu respuesta :)

Comment: Hola de nuevo Alan, no digo que sustituyas las variables a la fuerza, pero sí debes definir las constantes. 

Mira un ejemplo explicado:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214391/tcpdf-logo-header

suerte

Answer (score 0):

En la [documentación de TCPDF](https://tcpdf.org/docs/source_docs/classTCPDF/) busca qué parámetros recibe cada método y así hazlo. Usa valores directos o tus propias variables, no hay necesidad de sustituir constantes.

Por ejemplo para poner una imagen en la cabecera:

```
$this->pdf->SetHeaderData('/img/logo.png', 100, 'string to print as title on document header', 'string to print on document header');
```

A decir verdad, no entiendo la diferencia entre el tercer y cuarto parámetro... Tú prueba.